# Создание файлов с уникальными именами

Tags: c

Есть у меня каталог `/home/name/files` в который я хочу постоянно записывать файлы с уникальными именами. Как этого можно добиться с использованием языка си?

Comment: Uuid вам в помощь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053568/generating-a-random-uuid-in-c

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpnam

Comment: Используйте последовательные числа в качестве имён файлов

Answer (score 1):

В стандарте POSIX есть несколько функций которые помогут это сделать

```
int mkstemp(char *template);
char *mktemp(char *template);
FILE *tmpfile (void);
```