# Создание уникальных имен файлов в определенном каталоге

Tags: c

Нужно в заданном каталоге создавать файлы с уникальными именами, например в каталоге `usr/bin/files`. В [ответе на данный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1193069/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) предлагают использовать функции `mktemp`, `tmpfile` или `mkstemp`, но как я понял:

1 - Они создают уникальное имя во всей системе(или, наверное, в каталоге из которого была запущена программа), а мне нужно только в определенном каталоге

2 - Они имеют ограничения, например в функции `mktemp` количество уникальных имен ограничивается 6 символами, то есть 28^6, то есть около 4 миллионов уникальных файлов возможно создать, а мне нужны миллиарды как минимум

Как я могу создавать уникальные имена файлам в **определенном** каталоге используя только язык си?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Много непонятно. Например -  сильно сомневаюсь, что какая-то ОС сможет поддерживать каталог, в котором миллиарды файлов. Для того, что бы просто выполнить команду *ls* ОС должна прочитать в ОЗУ файл этого каталога. А его размер будет - много ГБайт... Дале, непонятно, Вам нужны уникальные имена, или случайные?Если просто уникальные - ну зазывайте их как faile0000000000 ... fille999999999999 - чем такой подход не устраивает? Если Вам неудобно следить за нумерацией файлов, называйте их по представлению текущего времени с точностью до микросекунд - они все будут разные.

Comment: Если вас интересует стандартная библиотечная функция, то нет (по крайней мере я о такой не знаю). Напишите такую функцию сами.